# boost::asio io_service thread pool with io_service::work

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool, asio

I have a boost::asio threadpool, which has a `asio::io_service` and `asio::work`:
    `boost::asio::io_service m_service;`
    `boost::asio::io_service::work m_work;`
In the threadpool destructor, I am calling `m_service.stop()` and then joining all the threads. However running into this crash intermittently during process shutdown (in the threadpool destructor):

```
    #0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
    #1  0x00007f4c8e59d160 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::destroy (
        this=0x6d579f8)
        at /home/depot/Boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:43
    #2  0x00007f4c8e59d115 in boost::asio::detail::op_queue_access::destroy (o=0x6d579f8)
        at /home/depot/Boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/detail/op_queue.hpp:47
    #3  0x00007f4c8e59d044 in boost::asio::detail::op_queue::~op_queue (this=0x6d57a20)
        at /home/depot/Boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/detail/op_queue.hpp:81
    #4  0x00007f4c8e685d65 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::~task_io_service (
        this=0x6d57960)
        at /home/depot/Boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service.hpp:40
    #5  0x00007f4c8e685dc9 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::~task_io_service (
        this=0x6d57960)
        at /home/depot/Boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service.hpp:40
    #6  0x00007f4c8e5aa1ce in boost::asio::detail::service_registry::destroy (
        service=0x6d57960)
        at /home/depot/Boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp:101
    #7  0x00007f4c8e68537c in boost::asio::detail::service_registry::~service_registry (
        this=0x6d55020)
        at /home/depot/Boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp:45
    #8  0x00007f4c8e6852b0 in boost::asio::io_service::~io_service (
        this=0x7f4c8eb169c8 )
        at /home/depot/Boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:53
    #9  0x00007f4c8e71d295 in crossplat::threadpool::~threadpool (
        this=0x7f4c8eb169b0 )
        at /home/depot/include/threadpool.h:87
    #10 0x00007f4c8aed6fe8 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0,
    ---Type  to continue, or q  to quit---
        listp=0x7f4c8b2605f8 , run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true)
        at exit.c:82
    #11 0x00007f4c8aed7035 in __GI_exit (status=) at exit.c:104
    #12 0x00007f4c8aebd837 in __libc_start_main (main=0x1ce0980 ,
        argc=3, argv=0x7fffee2eda98, init=, fini=,
        rtld_fini=, stack_end=0x7fffee2eda88) at ../csu/libc-start.c:325
    #13 0x0000000001cdf159 in _start () at /usr/include/c++/v1/string:2027
```

The asio documentation suggests to explicitly destroy the `asio::work` object for all handlers to finish normally. Questions:

1. Is it required to call `io_service::stop()` after explicitly destructing the asio::work object?
2. What is the difference between `io_service::stop()` and destroying `io_service::work`
3. Does this threadpool destructor look right, can it help fix the above crash. I have changed m_work to a pointer `std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_work;`:
   `~threadpool()`
   `{`
   `m_work.reset(); // Allow io_service::run to exit`
   `// join all threads`
   `}`

Comment: I am fairly certain you would not call io_service.stop if there was no posted work. You can test this by seeing if io_service::run returns after work is destroyed. Make sure you actually wait for the threads to exit with a call to join. I've never used threadpool, so I am not qualified to give an full fledged answer.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz threadpool must be his own code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it required to call io_service::stop() after explicitly destructing the asio::work object?

No. If there's no more work, the service will complete (poll/run will return).

> What is the difference between io_service::stop() and destroying io_service::work

Work just releases the lock, *allowing* the service to complete.

`io_service::stop()` forcibly stops the event loop, even if there was still work pending.

> Does this threadpool destructor look right, can it help fix the above crash.

Yes, the destructor should join all threads. Your code doesn't show it, so I suggest to verify you do that.

### Idea

I note the `threadpool` is being destroyed from an exit handler. This - to me - implies that threadpool likely has static storage duration. If it also depends on anything other (like, maybe, a static `io_service` instance?) you could be running into the [SIOF](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order): Static Initialization Order Fiasco.